# Is there a single command for vertical padding in LilyPond \markup?

Tags: software, lilypond

The [documentation](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/align) for `\markup` alignment lists two essentially different padding commands: `\pad-around` or `\pad-markup`, which adds the same amount of space all around the element, and `\pad-x`, which adds left and right padding while leaving the top and bottom unpadded.

Is there any one command that only adds vertical padding? Or do I need to do something like

`\pad-around #0.5 \pad-x #-0.5 { STUFF }`

to achieve that?

ETA: My overarching goal is to correctly white out the parts of bar lines that would otherwise intersect with expressive marks, like so:

[image: a score with "sostenuto" crossing a barline]

The full code can be found [here](http://lilybin.com/kqu9eb/6) at LilyBin.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use `\vspace`, e.g.

```
    \markup{ 
       \vspace #10
        stuff
       \vspace #10
    }
```

as per [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/22926/separate-the-top-matter-from-the-staves-in-lilypond)

Comment: Thanks. Hoist by my own petard! Unfortunately, I don't think this quite does what I want; Lilypond is a lot more aggressive about removing \vspace inside staves than it is about removing padding.

Answer (score 2):

This is a late answer, but are you familiar with the `/whiteout` command? It's a pre-defined tool that explicitly handles your "overarching" goal of barlines interfering with expressive marks. Something like `d^\markup { \italic \whiteout { sostenuto } }` will do the trick:

[image]

Full code [here](http://lilybin.com/0l37t4/1) at LilyBin.